# How to convert floating number to binary if I have no 32 bits for it

Tags: floating-point, binary, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a fractional number 1,76 to binary, but the size of the exponent is not 8 bits, but 3 bits, and the size of mantissa is not 23 bits, but 6 bits. That is, there are only 10 bits.

I get for 32-bit representation 0 01111111 11000010..... Can I just cut this representation?

Thanks.

Comment: You must have a precise specification of the format and there is no standard representation for 10 bits floats (and you probably have an eleventh bit for sign).  How is coded the exponent (maybe exp+3 if following ieee754 logic)? Is there a hidden bit? When you have this information, if the format is similar to ieee754 you will have to 1/ adjust the exponent and 2/ truncate (or preferably round) the mantissa to 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes a 10-bit format in the style of IEEE-754:

- There is a one-bit sign field, 0 for positive and 1 for negative.
- There is a three-bit exponent field with an exponent bias of three (2<sup>*e*</sup> is represented with *e*−3 in the field).
- There is a seven-bit significand, of which the trailing six bits are stored in a significand field and the leading bit is encoded by the exponent (zero in the exponent field indicates 0 for the leading significant bit, non-zero indicates 1, excluding infinities or NaNs).

To encode 1.76, we observe:

- It is positive, so the sign bit is 0.
- It equals *f*•2<sup>0</sup> where 1 ≤ *f* < 2, so the exponent *e* is 0.
- *f* is 1.76, which is, in binary, 1.1100001010001111…

Partitioning the significand into one leading bit, six bits for the significand field, and the residue, we have 1 110000 1010001111…. Since the residue is more than ½ the value of the preceding position, we round up, incrementing 1 110000 to 1 110001.

Thus, the encoding of 1.76 is 0 for the sign, 3 (011) for the exponent, and 110001 for the significand:

```
0 011 110001
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer you're looking for is:

```
0 011 110001
```

You can stop reading if that's all you cared about; but if you want to learn how I found it and how SMT-solvers can help answer such questions about floating-point numbers (amongst many others!), read on.

If you have 3 exponent bits, 6 significand bits, and 1 sign bit; then you have a total of 10 bits. Eric already explained the general schema on how to go for the conversion, but he used the 16-bit so called `half-precision` format. Since you have this non-standard format it doesn't directly answer your question. You can follow his reasoning and do the same for your format (you'll have to figure out the proper bias etc.), or use a tool to do all of that for you.

Modern SMT solvers can be used for such conversions with ease. An SMT solver is a kind of an automated theorem prover that can deal with different theories of interest, floating-point being one of them. And they support floats in the most general way: With user specified widths for exponent and significand.

- You can read more about SMT-solvers here: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/
- Floating-point logic is explained here: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FloatingPoint.shtml
- There are many SMT solvers, but perhaps the most popular one these days is z3 from Microsoft: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3

Having said all this, all we need to do is to ask the solver what the conversion would be to your particular format, given the number `1.76`. Here's how that problem is coded in the SMT-Lib language:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(define-fun x () (_ FloatingPoint 3 7) 
                 ((_ to_fp 3 7) roundNearestTiesToEven (/ 176.0 100.0)))
(check-sat)
(get-value (x))
```

It's a lisp-like language, as you can see. The floating-point type you're talking about is (somewhat confusingly) written as `(_ FloatingPoint 3 7)`. This means we have 3-exponent bits, and 7-bits for significand, *including* the hidden bit. The extra 1-bit for the sign is always there, so it's not explicitly mentioned.

Conversion is done with the function `(_ to_fp 3 7)`, which converts a given natural to the corresponding format. Note that it takes a rounding-mode as usual, and I picked the common mode `roundNearestTiesToEven`; but you can pick any of the five IEEE754 rounding modes. See the floating-point logic description for details. Finally, the rational number `1.76` is written as `(/ 176.0 100.0)`.

We told the solver to produce models in the very first line. The call `(check-sat)` says: Go ahead and find a model for all my constraints. And in the last line, we ask for the value of our floating-point number `x`.

Now if you put this program in a file, say `a.smt2`, and download [z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) on your computer and run it, you get:

```
$ z3 a.smt2
sat
((x (fp #b0 #b011 #b110001)))
```

What z3 is telling us is that indeed there is a solution. (Remember, you can put arbitrary constraints, so the system may not have a solution in general; in which case you'd have gotten an `unsat` answer.) Than it tells us what the value of `x` is. And you can squint and see the format as you requested:

```
0 011 110001
```

So, there you go, this is how you'd represent the number 1.76 in your particular floating-point format.

SMT solvers are pretty amazing, and they can do magical things; including free conversion to any specific floating-point format you might have!

Comment: Yes, I got “ten bits” stuck in my head and incorrectly used that for the significand field. I fixed my answer.